# How to populate a 2D array onto CollectionView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

Currently, I have a 2D array of 10 rows and 10 columns and I would like to print this using Collection View to the front end. However, I am only able to get the data on my first row in my 2D array to the collection view. I would like to retrieve all rows.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? WordSearchTableViewCell, let columns = grid.first?.count{
    //print(columns)
    let item = CGFloat(indexPath.item)
    //print("item: ", item)
    let row = floor(item / CGFloat(columns))
    //print("row: " , row)

    let column = item.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(columns))
    print("column: ",column)

    //setCharacter
    cell.charLabel.text = grid[Int(row)][Int(column)]
    return cell
    }
    print("error")
    return WordSearchTableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own question. So one mistake I think I did was I return only one row instead of 10 thus need to have numberOfSections.So even if the result was able to display, there is not enough collectionviewCell.

For the looping process, I set a counter that tracks the row number each time the column reaches the last element of the array for that row, there will be an increment.

Not sure if my explanation was right.

```
var counter: Int = 0

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //return columns
    return grid.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return rows
    return grid[section].count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? WordSearchTableViewCell, let columns = grid.first?.count{

        let item = indexPath.item
        let row : Int = counter
        let column : Int = Int(CGFloat(item).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(columns)))

        //rowNum + 1 each time reaches last item of column
        if column == 9 {
            counter = counter + 1
        }

    //setCharacter
    cell.charLabel.text = grid[row][column]
    return cell
    }

    print("error")
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? WordSearchTableViewCell, let columns = grid.first?.count{
    let item = indexPath.item
    let row : Int = item / numberOfRows+1 //11 in your case
    let column : Int = item % numberOfColumns+1 //11 in your case
    cell.charLabel.text = grid[row][column]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you please detail your answer? What is happening here? Why is there an "11" magic value?

Comment: @Ferdz it should be the number of `column+1` but in this case as he said there are 10 columns then it equals to 11